# Counter in Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a modal that will have a + / - counter.

However, I think since the state is in base component, modal is not able to recognize it. Any idea how to solve it?

I tried passing it as a prop but no luck

```
export default function ProgramCard() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const handleIncrement = () => {
    console.log(1)
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    };
    const handleDecrement = () => {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1);
    };

  const [opened, { open, close }] = useDisclosure(false);

  const openModal = () => modals.openConfirmModal({
    title: 'Input Data',
    children: (
      <div>
      <Button placeholder='-' onClick={handleDecrement}></Button>{"  #  "}{count}{"  #  "}
                            <Button placeholder='+' onClick={handleIncrement}></Button>
      </div>
    ),
    labels: { confirm: 'Confirm', cancel: 'Cancel' },
    onCancel: () => console.log('Cancel'),
    onConfirm: () => notifications.show({
      title: 'Input Submitted',
      message: 'Complete',
    }),
  });

  return (
    <Grid.Col span={2}>
      <Paper shadow="xs" radius="md" p="sm">
        <Text fw={700}>Sample</Text>
      <br></br>
      <Space h="xs" />
      <Button variant={'light'} radius="xl" size="xs" onClick={openModal}>
      Record
      </Button>
      
      </Paper>
    </Grid.Col>
    
  )
}
```

I tried passing it as a prop but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to pass the `handleIncrement`:

```
<Modal increment={handleIncrement} >
```

Because of how closures work in javascript, no matter where you call the `handleIncrement`, it will still have a reference to `setCount` which has reference to `count`

inside of `Modal` component, you might have a button

```
<button onClick={props.increment} >Increase</button>
```

Comment: Thanks...actually I realized I had uncalled <Modal...> which I removed now. I am actually calling the openModal. But not sure how to pass the prop to this way?